# Flattening a nested and repeated structure in BigQuery (standard SQL)

Tags: google-bigquery

There are a lot of posts on unnesting repeated fields in BigQuery -- but, being new to this environment, I have tried almost every code variation I found to flatten a data file.  But, I cannot seem to produce one without creating blanks in the `id` field.  It seem like I need to unflatten a nested variable?

I'm using a COVID Dimensions data set that is part of the public collection.  Here is some minimal code that produces my problem:

```
SELECT
   id,
   authors
FROM
   `covid-19-dimensions-ai.data.publications`
CROSS JOIN 
   UNNEST(authors)
LIMIT 1000
```

And, here is the JSON structure after running this query. Everything is flattened with the structure I want, but I don't know how to fill in / avoid the blank id variables.

```
{
    "id": "pub.1130234899",
    "authors": {
      "first_name": "Eric M",
      "last_name": "Yoshida",
      "initials": null,
      "researcher_id": "ur.01071531321.03",
      "grid_ids": [
        "grid.17091.3e"
      ],
      "corresponding": false,
      "raw_affiliations": [
        "Division of Gastroenterology, University of British Columbia, Vancouver, British Columbia, Canada"
      ],
      "affiliations_address": [
        {
          "grid_id": "grid.17091.3e",
          "city_id": "6173331",
          "state_code": "CA-BC",
          "country_code": "CA",
          "raw_affiliation": "Division of Gastroenterology, University of British Columbia, Vancouver, British Columbia, Canada"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

See small correction to your original query

```
SELECT
   id,
   author
FROM
   `covid-19-dimensions-ai.data.publications`
CROSS JOIN 
   UNNEST(authors) author
LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your corrections, and I am still getting the occasional missing id value within a group of records.  For example, an author will have complete information in one row.  However, if the author has 3 multiple affiliations, those affiliations properly expand to the rows, but the id is listed only for the first affiliation.

Comment: What the id? Need it to troubleshoot

Comment: These are publication records.  The `id` represents a unique publication.  `author` is a collection of fields and arrays.  When I unnest, the `id` values do not populate across all the rows.

Comment: I think you should update your question with more details!

Comment: Maybe screenshot with what you consider a problem, with how you want it to be